# The Mystery Of The Disappearing App Icons

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, home-screen-shortcuts, lg-optimus-one

If I try to rearrange the shortcuts to app icons on my homescreen, sometimes they disappear. It happens to all apps, bookmarks, and folders, too: even stock apps, like Play Store. I have an LG optimus s that I got about a year ago, new. I'm running 2.3.3. Gingerbread.
Details : app icons often reappear in folders after reboot, sometimes without reboot. I'll say again, for clarity, that this only happens when I attempt to rearrange the icons : no spontaneous disappearances! I use my phone almost 24/7, as I do not own a tablet or a computer with wifi, so I like everything to be in it's place.

Answer (score 2):

are you using the stock launcher? 
Clearing all data from your launcher app should sort of reset your app. 
You can try that from **Settings -> Applications -> (Launcher App)** and then hit the "Clear Data" button. You will lose your homescreen settings preferences.

Also, you can try using a different launcher like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) or [GO Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex). This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, tapping **Menu** → **Show more icons / Show less icons** (this should be "Show fewer icons", but w/e) does the trick usually.